# how can i make a TRibbonComboBox act like a TCombobox with Style of csDropDownList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ribbon

how can i make a TRibbonComboBox act like a TCombobox with Style of csDropDownList?  we don't want the user to be able to edit the choices in the list.

we need to use TRibbonComboBox because we want the current selection to be visible.

Microsoft word shows a combobox where you can select an item but cannot edit the item itself.

should i consider trying a TCombobox in the ribbon?  i'd expect it won't look or not work correctly.

thank you for you comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `TRibbonComboBox.ReadOnly`:

> Determines whether the user can change the text of the edit control.

And furthermore:

> Setting ReadOnly to true ensures that the text is not altered, while still allowing the user to select text. The selected text can then be manipulated by the application, or copied to the Clipboard.

(see [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/RibbonActnCtrls_TRibbonComboBox_ReadOnly.html))